# equation to get 10 points on circle surface at fix distance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

What I tried is :

$$x = \sin(36 \cdot 50 \cdot 3.14)/180$$

$$y = \cos(36 \cdot 50 \cdot 3.14)/180$$

Here

$36$ is because I want 10 points on circle so $360/10=36$.

$50$ is center X and center Y of circle. That is center point of circle is $(50,50)$.

$3.14$ is value of $\pi$

$180$ is again value of $\pi$ in radian

But it always returns $0,0$. How can I get $10$ points on circle surface at fix distance

Comment: If you can specify your points in polar coordinates, you're golden…

Comment: @mark Find all tenth roots of unity and plot them in the complex plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formulas are off.

You want the angles 
$$36^\circ,\ 2\cdot36^\circ,\ 3\cdot36^\circ,\   \ldots,\ 10\cdot36^\circ.$$

To convert degrees to radians, multiply by ${\pi\over 180}$.

So the angles in radians are 
$${36\pi\over 180} ,\  {2\cdot36\pi\over 180}  ,\  {3\cdot36\pi\over 180}   ,\ \ldots, {10\cdot36\pi\over 180}  .$$

With center $(50,50)$ and radius $r$,
the point $(x,y)$ on the circle is $$x=50+r \cos\theta, \quad y=50+r \sin\theta.$$
where $r$ is the radius of the circle (you didn't specify $r$).

So for the 36 degree angle, for example, the point is
$$\textstyle
x=50+r\cos(
{36\pi\over 180}  ),\quad
y=50+r\sin(
{36\pi\over 180}\cdot36 ).$$
or, simplifying
$$\textstyle
x=50+r\cos(
{ \pi\over5}  ),\quad
y=50+r\sin(
{ \pi\over5} ).$$

(Note the angles are just ${\pi\over 5}$, ${2\pi\over 5}$, $\ldots\,$, ${10\pi\over 5}$.)

You could save some computational effort by taking advantage of symmetry:

The three points in the "first quadrant" of the circle are (corresponding to the angles ${10\pi\over5}=2\pi\sim0$, ${\pi\over 5}$, and ${2\pi\over5}$):

$$\textstyle
( 50+r,50  ),\quad (50+r\cos{\pi\over5}, \quad 50+\sin{\pi\over5}),\quad  (50+r\cos{2\pi\over5}, 50+\sin{2\pi\over5}) 
$$

The three points in the "second quadrant" of the circle are (corresponding to  the angles ${5\pi/5}=\pi $, ${3\pi\over 5}$, and ${4\pi\over5}$):

$$\textstyle
( 50-r,50  ),\quad (50-r\cos{\pi\over5}, \quad 50+\sin{\pi\over5}),\quad  (50-r\cos{2\pi\over5}, 50+\sin{2\pi\over5}) 
$$

And to get the other four points in the "bottom half" of the circle, take the points above, except $(50+r,50)$ and $50-r,50)$, and switch the sign before the "$\sin$" in the $y$ coordinates.

---

[image]